# How can i put command output into a variable

Tags: bash

Trying to run the following bash script. The output of the following ling fails:

```
mem = free | grep Mem | awk '{print $4/$2 * 100}'
```

With the error:

> mem: command not found

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
mem=$(free | grep Mem | awk '{print $4/$2 * 100}')
```

You can also use backticks:

```
mem=`free | grep Mem | awk '{print $4/$2 * 100}'`
```

But parentheses are preferred now. More: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082